# How can I run commands on each page of outputs from pdftotext?

Tags: bash, pdf, sed

I have a PDF file with a matrix which I want to use for computational purposes. Each page of the PDF file has some unwanted text above and below the matrix.

I can output the pdf pages to text via this.

```
pdftotext input.pdf -layout
```

Then I strip off the unwanted lines with this.

```
sed -e '1, 19d' < input.txt | head -n -7 > output.txt
```

But this only works for one page. There are over 60 pages in the PDF. I can extract a single page from pdftotext by running:

```
pdftotext input.pdf -f 1 -l 1 -layout
```

Is it possible to run a loop on each page, perform transformations, then cat the text files together?

Comment: why not puting markers like deletefrom## deleteto## and via sed command sed '/marker1/,/marker2/d' or similar. Time spent for asking this question maybe is enough to solve that via text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
#! /bin/sh
pages=$(pdfinfo input.pdf | awk '/^Pages:/ {print $2}')
{
    let p=0
    while [ $p -lt $pages ]; do
        pdftotext input.pdf -f $p -l $p -layout
        let p++
    done
} >output.txt
```